# Change Boolean from a String to a checkbox (JTable)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcheckbox

I am having a small problem of showing results from my database to a JTable. It displays all of the data correctly, but at the moment it is showing "true" or "false" for boolean.

I know it must be because I am using `getString`, but does anyone know what to use in order to change it to a checkbox instead?

Current JTable:

[image]

My Database:

[image]

Code:

```
connection con=new connection();
Connection getcon=null;
Vector col = new Vector();
Vector dat= new Vector();
ResultSet rs = null;
try{
    getcon = con.creatConnection();
    col.add("Fanta");
    col.add("Crisps");
    col.add("Beer");
    col.add("Wine");// create income table default colum names and sore it
    col.add("Water");
    col.add("Seat Row");
    col.add("Seat");
    col.add("Total Cost");  
    rs=getcon.createStatement().executeQuery("select*from orders"); //getting all the information from the table

    dat.clear();

    while(rs.next()){// if record source avilable

        Vector v =new Vector();
        v.add(rs.getString("Fanta").trim());
        v.add(rs.getString("Crisps").trim());
        v.add(rs.getString("Beer").trim());
        v.add(rs.getString("Wine").trim());// getting income values from database and store in dat
        v.add(rs.getString("Water").trim());
        v.add(rs.getString("SeatRow").trim());
        v.add(rs.getString("Seat").trim());
        v.add(rs.getString("TotalCost").trim());

        dat.add(v);
    }
    orderResults.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(dat, col));
}
catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Have you tried [`rs.getBoolean("FieldName")`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getBoolean(java.lang.String))?

Comment: Yeah, it gives the same result unfortunately. :/

Comment: [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to save data as a Boolean in your model. So you should use this `rs.getBoolean("Fanta")` instead of `rs.getString("Fanta").trim()`.

Second, you have to override a `public Class getColumnClass(int column)` method from your `JTable`. Your code could look like this:

```
JTable orderResults = new JTable() {
    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int column) {
        // first 5 columns will be represented as an checkbox
        if(column <= 4){
            return Boolean.class;
        }

        // rest of them as a text
        return String.class;
    }
};
```